# Random memory address

Tags: memory, glibc

I'm working on a virtual machine under Debian with EGLIBC 2.13 in order to learn memory address.
So I wrote a simple code giving me the address of a test variable, but everytime I exec this script, I'm getting a totally different address.

Here's two screens from 2 distincts executions :

[image]

[image]

What's causing this ? The fact I'm working on a VM or my GLIBC version ?
I guess it's GLIBC to prevent buffer overflow but I can't find my answer on the web.
And is it totally random ?

Comment: BTW, you might use Debian testing (or Linux Mint) in a VM for development purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (from GTK) is not [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (a.k.a. `glibc`)

Then, you are observing the effect of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) (address space layout randomization). Don't try to disable it on a server *directly* connected to the Internet, it is a valuable security measure.

ASLR is mostly provided by the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (e.g. when handing [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) *without* `MAP_FIXED`, as most implementations of `malloc` do, and probably also at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time for the initial stack). Changing your [`libc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (e.g. to [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) won't disable it.

You could disable system-wide ASLR on a laptop (or on a Linux system running inside some VM) using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html): run

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

as root. Be careful, by doing that you are decreasing the security of your system.

I don't know what you call *totally random*, but ASLR is *random enough*. IIRC, (but I might be wrong) the middle 32 bits of the 64-bits address (assuming a 64 bits Linux system) are quite random, to the point of making result of `mmap` (hence of `malloc` using it) practically unpredictable and non-reproducible.

BTW, to see ASLR in practice, try several times (with ASLR enabled) the following command

```
 cat /proc/self/maps
```

this command displays a textual representation of the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running that `cat` command. You'll see different outputs when you run it several times !

For debugging [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). With a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9 or better (or *recent* [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) compiler, the [address sanitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is also useful, so you could compile with `gcc` then  `-Wall -Wextra`  to get all the warnings even the extra ones, then `-g` to get debug info, then `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: Ok so it's none of the two possibilities I was thinking, perfect ! : )
No, I'll don't disactivate it, don't worry. I guess attackers must have real bad times guessing memory address with it !

Comment: I don't worry. In practice, when debugging low-level memory issues in C (or even C++) with `gdb` I am disabling ASLR to have more reproducible runs.

Comment: Thanks for the lot of informations and link, I'll check it all.
But it means ASLR don't work on MacOS and Windows ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, both *recent* MacOSX and Windows have ASLR. But I don't know, I don't use MacOSX or Windows (and I nearly never used them, while coding since 1974).

Comment: ASLR is implemented since Windows Server 2008 and Vista for Microsoft, and MacOS 10.5 (Léopard). It's quite reassuring.